# How to fix this'FIRApp' has different definitions in different modules; first difference is defined here found property?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

Could not build module 'Firabase'
[Problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ReWZj.png)

I tried to update GoogleMobileSdk. I deleted Subfile.lock, the Pods folder and then added to Subfile - under 'Google-Mobile-Ads-SDK' I had a problem that it didn't detect @import GoogleMobileAds ;, but I did drag-and-drop and it worked, but another came out error. The one I showed in the photo above that there is a problem with Firebase

Comment: same issue here. have you fix the error? @Miroslav